# Use setUpdateListener on api level lower than 19

Tags: android, animation

For an animation i have to listen to every step of the **ViewPropertyAnimator**. I use the `AnimatorUpdateListener` in combination with the `setUpdateListener`.

source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html

*Example how i use it:*

```
image.animate().translationY(transY).setDuration(duration).setUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

       @Override
       public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
           // do my things
       }
});
```

Now im moving an object from A to B and have to `detect` some things while moving. Now setUpdateListener is really helpful with this, and with this code it all works. But its requires api level 19. I really want to use api level 14 for this project. Is there an alternative for `setUpdateListener`?

*ViewPropertyAnimator.setUpdateListener*

```
Call requires api level 19 (current min is 14)
```

Comment: Can you use a valueanimator? It looks like its addUpdateListener only requires api 11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With **API level 19** or above you can say

```
image.animate()
     .translationY(transY)
     .setDuration(duration)
     .setUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

         @Override
         public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
             // do my things
         }

     });
```

With **API level 11** or above you can resort to:

```
ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, View.TRANSLATION_Y, transY)
                                  .setDuration(duration);
oa.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        // do my things
    }
});
oa.start();
```

NOTE: While `ViewProperyAnimator` calls `View.setHasTransientState()` under the hood for the animated view, `ObjectAnimator` does not. This can result in different behavior when doing custom (i.e. not with `ItemAnimator`) `RecyclerView` item animations.

Answer (score 7):

Below is an improvement of Zsolt's answer with the listener code in one place and a code-level check of the API version:

```
ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener updateListener = new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        // do my things
    }     
};

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    image.animate()
          .translationY(transY)
          .setDuration(duration)
          .setUpdateListener(updateListener);
} else {

    ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, View.TRANSLATION_Y, transY)
                                  .setDuration(duration);
    oa.addUpdateListener(updateListener);
    oa.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 9OldAndroid lib.. it backported Honeycomb (Android 3.0) animation API on all versions of the platform back to 1.0!

Rference link
https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/

Comment: The problem is that api 19 contains a method (`setUpdateListener`) that api's lower than 19 do not have. So deprecated/older methods missing on api level 19 is not the problem. Its the other way around. I searched in the library but can't find for an alternative for setUpdateListener.